# Photogallary is appear in portrait mode even though iPhone is in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ipad, photo-gallery, landscape-portrait

Hi all I  set the device in landscape mode, in that mode while I press the "photo gallery" button the gallery is open in the portrait mode and after choose the pic from gallery it will come back to landscape mode. I want to open the gallery in landscape mode when i working in landscape mode.

I used this code to open photogallery

```
- (void)imagesFromGallery{
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
{
    if(!popover) 
    {
        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
    }

    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(500, 620, 0, 0)
                             inView:self.view
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp 
                           animated:YES];
}
else 
{
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}   }
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Photo gallery always opens in the Portrait mode, you can not do anything to change it into Landscape mode.except if you fetch all the images and make a view of your own. That is going to be very tedious!

Comment: Before posting questions like this, PLEASE READ THE DOCS. Apple provide all the reference for a reason. It would have taken less time to search the docs than to post this question. [To quote the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) "Important The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Presenting it

```
 [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Add the imagePickerView to the self.view and set the frame of the imagePicker

```
[self.view addSubview:imagePicker.view];
```

Hope it Will Work for You.!!

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works fine. But once you loaded the image gallery, scrolling the view and selecting the folder is a problem.

Subclassing the `UIImagepicker` is the right option. Just create a class which is subclass of `UIImagepicker` and add the below method.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Rest, asusual alloc this viewcontroller and present.